# jQuery UI - Accordion Display issues

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

My accordion is working properly, but I'm having a JS issue that are prohibiting it from displaying correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/frEWQ/4/

1. The JS is not applying .ui-corners-all to the H3 after the "kwick" div below it has finished collapsing, giving an odd cut-off border after the animation

Any suggestions?

Thanks

```
        // find elements to show and hide
    var toShow = clicked.next(),
        toHide = this.active.next(),
        data = {
            options: o,
            newHeader: clickedIsActive && o.collapsible ? $([]) : clicked,
            oldHeader: this.active,
            newContent: clickedIsActive && o.collapsible ? $([]) : toShow,
            oldContent: toHide
        },
        down = this.headers.index( this.active[0] ) > this.headers.index( clicked[0] );

    this.active = clickedIsActive ? $([]) : clicked;
    this._toggle(toShow, toHide, data, clickedIsActive, down);

    // switch classes
    this.active.removeClass("ui-state-active ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-state-default ui-corner-all")
        .find(".ui-icon").removeClass(o.icons.headerSelected).addClass(o.icons.header);
    if (!clickedIsActive) {
        clicked.removeClass("ui-state-default ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-state-active ui-corner-top")
            .find(".ui-icon").removeClass(o.icons.header).addClass(o.icons.headerSelected);
        clicked.next().addClass('ui-accordion-content-active');
    }

    return;
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated:
You could modify the source, but that isn't generally a good idea.

Because it's expecting that specific format you may need to do something tricky with CSS to avoid that flicker.

- How about have full 20px border-radius on all corners of the h3 at all times, even when the element is expanded.
- Have the content use some styles like the following:
  `padding-top:20px; position:relative; top:-20px;` or something similar that will pad 20px and then correct the position by pulling it back up. That way, when it expands it's actually overlapping the `h3` bottom corners. If that didn't work `padding-top:20px; margin-top:-20px;` might.

In my mind this works. I'd try it on your jfiddle post but you haven't put the css source into the css frame.

Comment: yes, i actually tried to wrap the h3 and div together, but it seemed to break the javascript... didn't think of putting the div inside of the h3, i suppose that could work though not being legal.... i know it has to do with editing the javascript code added up top

Comment: You could just use another div instead of an h3 to avoid the conflict.

Comment: yeah, like i said i gave that a shot but it broke the javascript. i think it is expecting a specific structure in order to run properly. I've updated my question and code above with my findings so far

Comment: You're right sorry. I have another solution that might work, i'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Dave - Just a heads up that I edited the answer in case you didn't notice.